# Favorites in navigation pane Windows 7 sort order

Tags: windows-7, registry, favorites

I would like to get hold of the favorites links sort order, as seen when adding a folder it is placed at the bottom of the list where you then can drag that to any position.

Is there any registry hack or similar which you can get and change that order? I would always like it to be sorted in alphabetic order without me having to change everything around all the time.I've been searching around but can't find anything that helps me with this, I would like to know which registry that controls the order of the Favorites list in Navigation Pane in windows 7? not the Internet Explorer favorites...

Answer (score 1):

I use a weird but efficient way. I export entire the key FAVORITES, then I sort for my mental order, then delete entirely FAVORITES on registry and finally I import the file.reg previously sorted.
I think the problem is assign a valid name at a favorite, using a regular sintax, to better understand where it takes us. however this task can be don with a simply routine batch.
/tux01

Comment: before exporting you can sort them in registry by running PowerShell: 
$p = Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Applets\Regedit\Favorites' 
$p.PSObject.Properties | Sort-Object Value| Format-Table Name,Value

Answer (score 0):

No there is no supported way of programmatically reordering favorites. Imagine if there were: Every application would move themselves to the top!

Answer (score -2):

When you link a location to the Favorites folder, it is placed at the bottom of the list.  You can then drag it to any position using the mouse.